# Expected value of X for each value of Y (R)

Tags: r

So, I have a dataset of baseball players and am trying to calculate the expected value of their height, given their weight. I know how to calculate expected values within one variable, but I'm not quite sure how to do it using another?

I have included my dataset below. Using a dput command, I guess at the moment I've played around with various mutate commands but I don't know how to code something that works like expectedheight = mean(heightunches) if weightpounds = weightpounds. Because the expected value needs to take into consideration weightpounds.

```
structure(
  list(Name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Adam_Donachie", "Paul_Bako", "Ramon_Hernandez"), class = "factor"), 
       Team = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label ="BAL", class = "factor"), 
       Position = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Catcher",class = "factor"), 
       Heightinches = c(74L, 74L, 72L), Weightpounds =c(180L, 215L, 210L), 
       Age = c(22.98999977, 34.68999863, 30.78000069)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), 
  .Names = c("Name", "Team", "Position", "Heightinches", "Weightpounds", "Age"), 
  class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This sounds like a statistical methods question rather than a coding problem. Do you want, for example, predicted heights given weight (e.g., from a regression estimate)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could for example use linear regression

```
model <- lm( Weightpounds ~ Heightinches,dat)

model

Call:
lm(formula = Weightpounds ~ Heightinches, data = dat)

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)  Heightinches  
      660.00         -6.25
```

Meaning that

```
Weightpounds = 660 - 6.25*Heightinches
```

You can also then apply the model to data

```
> model <- lm( Weightpounds ~ Heightinches,dat)
> predict(model,dat)
1     2     3 
197.5 197.5 210.0
```

This uses a very simple linear model.

You can extend the model by extending the *formula* `Weightpounds ~ Heightinches` for the syntax check `?formula`

Comment: Rather than manual calculations, show how to use `predict()`.

Comment: You are both gentlemen and scholars. Thank you.